# Java update jLabel.setText via for loop

Tags: java, swing, loops, jlabel, settext

I basically checked out a book from the Library and started learning Java.  I'm trying to code a little score calculator for my golf league and this site has been a lof of help!  So thanks for even being here!

Now to the question:

I have a 9 labels, created with NetBeans GUI, with names like jLabel_Hole1, jLabel_Hole2, ...

If a user selects the radio option to play the front nine those labels have number 1 - 9 and if they change it to the "Back Nine" then they should display 10 - 18.  I can manually set each label to the new value on a selection change but I wanted to know if there was a more elegant way and if so if one of you could be kind enough to explain how it works.

Here is the code that I want to try and truncate:

```
       TGL.jLbl_Hole1.setText("10");
       TGL.jLbl_Hole2.setText("11");
       TGL.jLbl_Hole3.setText("12");
       TGL.jLbl_Hole4.setText("13");
       TGL.jLbl_Hole5.setText("14");
       TGL.jLbl_Hole6.setText("15");
       TGL.jLbl_Hole7.setText("16");
       TGL.jLbl_Hole8.setText("17");
       TGL.jLbl_Hole9.setText("18");
```

I've read some things about String being immutable and maybe it's just a limitation but I would think there has to be way and I just can't imagine it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you using an array for these labels?  Then you can use a loop and avoid this copy-pasted messy situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, rather then creating a individual label for each hole, you should create an array of labels, where each element in the array represents a individual hole.

So instead of...

```
TGL.jLbl_Hole1.setText("10");
TGL.jLbl_Hole2.setText("11");
TGL.jLbl_Hole3.setText("12");
TGL.jLbl_Hole4.setText("13");
TGL.jLbl_Hole5.setText("14");
TGL.jLbl_Hole6.setText("15");
TGL.jLbl_Hole7.setText("16");
TGL.jLbl_Hole8.setText("17");
TGL.jLbl_Hole9.setText("18");
```

You would have...

```
for (JLabel label : TGL.holeLables) {
    lable.setText(...);
}
```

A better solution would be to hide the labels from the developer and simply provide a setter...

```
TGL.setHoleText(hole, text); // hole is int and text is String
```

Internally to your `TGL` class, you have two choices...

If you've used the form editor in Netbeans, you're going to have to place the components that Netbeans creates into your own array...

```
private JLabel[] holes;
//...//
// Some where after initComponents is called...
holes = new JLabel[9];
holes[0] = jLbl_Hole1;
// There other 8 holes...
```

Then you would simply provide a setter and getter methods that can update or return the value...

```
public void setHole(int hole, String text) {
    if (hole >= 0 && hole < holes.length) {
        holes[hole].setText(text);
    }
}

public String getHole() {
    String text = null;
    if (hole >= 0 && hole < holes.length) {
        text = holes[hole].getText();
    }
    return text;
}
```

Take a closer look at the [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) tutorial for more details...

Answer (score 1):

I've never found a Java GUI-generator to provide code that's any good.  I may be wrong--there may be a good one, but I always prefer to position and name them myself.  So,

```
/**
 * The JLabels for the holes on the golf course.
 * <p>
 * holeLabels[0][i] are for the outward holes, 1-9.
 * holeLabels[1][i] are for the inward holes, 10-18.
 */
private JLabel[][] holeLabels;
/**
 * The starts of the outward and inward ranges of holes.
 */
private static final int[] holeStart = {1, 10};

// Later
holeLabels = new JLabel[2][9];
for(final int i = 0; i < holeLabels.length; i++) {
    for (final int j = 0; j < holeLabels[i].length; j++) {
        holeLabel[i][j] = new JLabel();
        holeLabel[i][j].setText(Integer.toString(holeStart[i] + j));
    }
}
```

Interestingly, `holeLabels.length` is `2`.  `holeLabels` is an array of 2 arrays of 9 `int`s.  `i` goes from `0` to `1`, and `j` goes from `0` to `8`, so the text computation works.  The reason I did things this way is so you can easily place the labels in an appropriate `GridLayout` later.

Comment: Thanks! I know I'll eventually have to learn Swing without the crutch of GUI generator.